# Internet Guest Account in Windows 2008 for permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, web-server, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have seen there's no "**Internet Guess Account**" user in Windows Server 2008.

I am trying to configure permissions over some folders in a website under ISS 7.5 and I am having troubles as I used that user to do it in Windows 2003.

How should I do it now in a secure way? I want to give write and execution permissions over an specific folder.

(The website is in PHP)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The IUSR account is a new account with w2k8.  By default that is the user account for anonymous.  I recommend setting the anonymous to inherit from application pool identity.  Then you can grant permissions on the ApplicationPoolIdentity I_AppPoolName account

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2005172

Either way is fine depending on your needs.